# How to change two separate list of list to single list of list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy

```py
list1=[[-0.2816765  -0.40262915 -0.71102916  0.81753135 -0.05980419]]
list2=[[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

I should get my output as

```py
output=[[-0.2816765  -0.40262915 -0.71102916  0.81753135 -0.05980419 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

How to perform this?

Comment: You ask about lists, though the displays omit the usual commas.  If these really are numpy arrays, say so. Don't mix up the two.  You'll get better answers.  You may need to read more of the numpy documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
# python lists
output = [list1[0] + list2[0]]

# numpy arrays:
output = np.hstack([list1, list2])
```

Comment: output = [list1[0] + list2[0]] and i got error ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (15,)

Comment: @SrinivasanVenkatramanan, Your question doesn't mention numpy. Please be more verbose/specific next time and spend some time for reproducible examples.

Comment: Okay. It is working. Thank you for your help

Comment: @SrinivasanVenkatramanan, please, accept the answer if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

> Simply use list.extend() method

```
list1 = [[-0.2816765, - 0.40262915 ,- 0.71102916 , 0.81753135 ,- 0.05980419]]
list2 = [[1,2,3,4,5]]

list1[0].extend(list2[0])

print(list1)


output::
>>>[[-0.2816765, -0.40262915, -0.71102916, 0.81753135, -0.05980419, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: `extend` mutates the original array. use carefully.